# configuring huawei e303e dongle on arm9 embedded board

Tags: linux, 3g, arm, dongle, linux-device-driver

i have been trying to connect 3g modem on arm9 board. bot modem is not getting detected. 
    here is my lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

and my dmesg is giving something like dis:

```
scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
sr0: scsi-1 drive
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
scsi 5:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
```

i have installed usb_modeswitch for arm.
when i run usb modeswitch command:
usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf -v 0x12d1 -p 0x14fe -W

```
Warning: TargetProductList overrides TargetProduct!
 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 1.1.4 (C) Josua Dietze 2010
 * Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x14fe
TargetVendor=   0x12d1
TargetProduct=  not set
TargetClass=    not set
TargetProductList="14fe,1506"

DetachStorageOnly=0
HuaweiMode=1
SierraMode=0
SonyMode=0
GCTMode=0
MessageEndpoint=  not set
MessageContent=""
NeedResponse=0
ResponseEndpoint= not set
Interface=0x00

InquireDevice enabled (default)
Success check disabled
System integration mode disabled


Looking for target devices ...
searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0001
searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:14fe
     found matching vendor ID
  found matching product ID from list
 Found devices in target mode or class (1)
Looking for default devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0001
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:14fe
found matching vendor ID
found matching product ID
 adding device
Found devices in default mode or class (1)
Accessing device 004 on bus 002 ...
 Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
 Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
 Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ...
 Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver found ("dummy")
 OK, driver "dummy" detached

SCSI inquiry data (for identification)
-------------------------
  Vendor String: HUAWEI  
    Model String: Mass Storage    
Revision String: 2.31
-------------------------

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI
  Product: HUAWEI Mobile
    Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Sending Huawei control message ...
 OK, Huawei control message sent
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.

root@arago:/etc/udev/rules.d# scsi 5:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
```

so wen again i run lsusb command:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

usb is detecting as mass storage. and it is not detecting as modem.

usb_modeswitch.conf

```
DisableSwitching=0                                                           
# Enable logging (results in a extensive report file in /var/log, named
# "usb_modeswitch_<interface-name>"                                    

EnableLogging=1                                                        
DefaultVendor = 0x12d1             
DefaultProduct = 0x1506
MessageEndPoint = "0x01"
iMessageContent = "55534243000000000000000000000011060000000000000000 0000000000
TargetVendor = 0x12d1                                                           
TargetProductList="14fe,1506"                                                   
HuaweiMode = 1
```

do i need to write any rules for usb_modeswitch? there is no rule files in my /lib/udev
and there are some files in /etc/udev/rules.d.

why my 3g dongle is getting detected as massstorage not as modem? what else i need to do?
 please help me asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first insert usb_wan.ko, option.ko,async.ko.
in /lib/udev/rules.d write 40-usb_modeswitch.rules
then run modeswitch.
and for wvdial configuration this site helped me
http://www.sisalik.ee/janek/wp/arhiiv/223